# Spring batch reader, processor and writer flow

Tags: java, batch-processing, spring-batch

i have a batch step

```
  <batch:step id="read-process-input-file">
  <batch:tasklet>
    <batch:chunk commit-interval=1000
                 reader="item-reader"
                 processor="item-processor"
                 writer="item-writer"
                 skip-limit=1000>

      <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        <batch:include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
      </batch:skippable-exception-classes>

    </batch:chunk>
  </batch:tasklet>
  <batch:listeners>
    <batch:listener ref="entityOperationExceptionHandler"/>
    <batch:listener ref="filenameListener"/>
    <batch:listener ref="promotionListener"/>
  </batch:listeners>
</batch:step>
```

- How does reader and processor flow works?Does reader reads a chunk and waits for processor to process it or it reads all the chunks in a go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reader is called to read one item, which is then passed to the processor. The result of the processor is cached. This is repeated until the commit interval has been reached. The cached processor results will then be passed to the writer, and the transaction committed.

If there is more work to do, the whole sequence starts again.

All this is happening in one thread, so the reading - processing - reading - processing ... is done sequentially.

**UPDATE:** I just learned that this is not strictly true. The sequence I described is certainly valid for the JSR 352 implementation of Spring Batch (which is what I was using), and since the documentation stated the same for the "classic" implemetation I assumed it must be true.

However, the answer to this question shows that there is a difference: [Spring Batch documentation about chunk-oriented step versus reality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655281/spring-batch-documentation-about-chunk-oriented-step-versus-reality)

So, for the non-JSR 352 implementation the sequence is reading - reading - reading ... processing - processing - processing ... writing

Comment: the writer that i have used in this is a FlatFileItemReader and the chunk size is 1000. So will the reader read 1000 lines and pass it to processor or will it read 1 line then pass it to processor then next and so on

Comment: It will read one line, then pass it to the processor, then read the next line etc.

Comment: is there a way that reader reads the chunk and then send it to processor.

Comment: In chunk based processing spring batch control the read - process - write cycle. If you need more control you can make a Tasklet step, as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#taskletStep

Comment: @Thomas is there any other alternative solution to get the reading - processing - reading - processing ... is done sequentially without JSR

Comment: I have the similar setup on flatfile reader. I have 10K records in csv file. While processing it reads and commits with interval of 100. At the end of the job I could see only 6.2K records are processed. i.e, 62 total commits of 100 records each. I am not sure why it is failing to process remaining records in my file.